# Make a better approach to wrap multiple lists/ dictionary inside class and looping key and value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I made this code for associative array

```
var data = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,List<int>>>() {
   {100, new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() {
      {"first", new List<int>() {4, 24, 5, 0}},
      {"second", new List<int>() {42, 58, 23, 8}} //TODO - add third, fourth etc.
   }},
   {500, new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() {
      {"first", new List<int>() {4, 24, 5, 0}},
      {"second", new List<int>() {42, 58, 23, 8}} //TODO - add third, fourth etc.
   }}
}
```

After that I thought that This feels very unintuitive in C#: Wrapping multiple Lists/Dictionarys inside each other isn't the most elegant solution.

So I made it  might be a better approach to wrap this construct inside classes:

```
public class DataContainer {
      public int Index { get; set; }
      public DataValue MyValue { get; set; }`enter code here`
    }

    public class DataValue {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<int> IntegerValues { get; set; }
    }
```

I made list of DataContainer like this in main

```
var data = new List<DataContainer>()
            {
                new DataContainer{index = 100 , DataValue = new DataValue
                {name = "first", IntegerValues = {5,4,5,5}}},
                 new DataContainer{index = 100 , DataValue = new DataValue
                {name = "second", IntegerValues = {10,45,5,65}}},
                 new DataContainer{index = 100 , DataValue = new DataValue
                {name = "third", IntegerValues = {10,45,5,65}}}


            };
```

but i got an exception , i try to fix it but i get an exception again

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=FalaqHijriyyah
  StackTrace:
       at FalaqHijriyyah.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Console\FalaqHijriyyah\FalaqHijriyyah\Program.cs:line 13
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

How to do that and i want to loop that key and value ?

Comment: If you get a run-time exception, make sure you paste the *exact* text of the exception and the line it occurs on.

Comment: I have added the exception

Comment: DataValue = new DataValue... should not be MyValue = new DataValue?

Comment: you can answer completely

Comment: @DrewKennedy - incorrect, you do not need parenthesis when using initializer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `NullReference` happends because the `List<int>` of `IntegerValues` is never created.

You could change your code like this:

```
  var data = new List<DataContainer>()
        {
            new DataContainer{Index = 100 , MyValue = new DataValue
            {Name = "first", IntegerValues = new List<int>{5,4,5,5}}},
             new DataContainer{Index = 100 , MyValue = new DataValue
            {Name = "second", IntegerValues = new List<int>{10,45,5,65}}},
             new DataContainer{Index = 100 , MyValue = new DataValue
            {Name = "third", IntegerValues = new List<int>{10,45,5,65}}}
        };
```

`IntegerValues` is not properly created: indestead of `{5,4,5,5}`, use `new List<int> ...`

---

You could also keep your syntax and use a static object initializer:

```
public class DataValue {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<int> IntegerValues = new List<int>();
}
```

then you can create `DataValue` like this:

```
new DataValue {Name = "first", IntegerValues = {5,4,5,5}}
```

---

Looping over the Integers (or anything else) is as easy as that:

```
        foreach(DataContainer dataContainer in data) {
            foreach (int intValue in dataContainer.MyValue.IntegerValues) {
                Console.WriteLine(intValue);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Loop over new List<DataContainer>() ?

Comment: no i want to loop through the index and the result will be like this 
index = 100 => 5,4,5,5                                                                                        
index = 500 => 10,45,5,65

Answer (score 0):

When using {get;set;} you need to initialize your List<> object in a constructor.

```
    public class DataValue {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<int> IntegerValues { get; set; }

      public DataValue()
      {
          IntegerValues = new List<int>();
      }
    }
​
```

Comment: You only need to do it once for each DataValue.  The loop is done every time a DataValue is created automatically.