# foreach loop data index as the key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have been trying to make for each loop with the index as the key 
this case i want to made a    logic if the input user is match with index and i will show foreach all of the data which has index as the key

I made two class like this

```
class DataContainer
    {

        public DataContainer()
        {

        }


        public int index { get; set; }
        public List<DataValue> DataValue { get; set; }
    }
    class DataValue
    {
        public DataValue()
        {

            IntegerValues = new List<int>();
        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<int> IntegerValues { get; set; }
    }
```

after that i try to make list of datacontainer like this

```
List<DataContainer> harakatSininilMabsutoh = new List<DataContainer>(){
        new DataContainer{index = 2015 , DataValue = new List<DataValue>()
         {
             new DataValue{name = "first",IntegerValues = {9,55,18,11}},
             new DataValue{name = "second"   ,IntegerValues = {5,54,18,11}},
             new DataValue{name = "third" ,IntegerValues = {40,26,14,11}},
             new DataValue{name = "four"    ,IntegerValues = {22,0,5,10}},
             new DataValue{name = "fifth"    ,IntegerValues = {46,44,17,0}},

         }
         },
          new DataContainer{index = 2013 , DataValue = new List<DataValue>()
         {
             new DataValue{name = "first",IntegerValues = {26,49,8,11}},
             new DataValue{name = "second"   ,IntegerValues = {19,42,8,11}},
             new DataValue{name = "third" ,IntegerValues = {55,3,12,11}},
             new DataValue{name = "fourth"    ,IntegerValues = {27,4,23,8}},
             new DataValue{name = "fifth"    ,IntegerValues = {43,22,7,1}},

         }
         },
          new DataContainer{index = 2001, DataValue = new List<DataValue>()
         {
             new DataValue{name = "first",IntegerValues = {35,44,27,10}},
             new DataValue{name = "second"   ,IntegerValues = {24,41,27,10}},
             new DataValue{name = "third" ,IntegerValues = {36,30,26,10}},
             new DataValue{name = "fourth"    ,IntegerValues = {59,24,8,6}},
             new DataValue{name = "fifth"    ,IntegerValues = {29,27,26,1}},

         }
          }
   };
```

and then i made a logic like this

```
    int years = (this is user input);
    if(years == 2015)
{
    ///How to for each this which has index 2015
}
else if (years = 2013)
{
         //how to foreach this which has index 2013
}
else if (years = 2001)
{
         //how to foreach this which has index 2001
```

[image]

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: So What is the Question?

Comment: I want to loop the data with index as the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is by using `LINQ` `FirstOrDefault` like this

```
int userinput = 2015;
DataContainer requested = harakatSininilMabsutoh.FirstOrDefault(x => x.index == userinput);
if (requested == null) //FirstOrDefault of a class will return null if not found
    return;
foreach (DataValue val in requested.DataValue) 
    Console.WriteLine(val.name + ": " + string.Join(", ", val.IntegerValues));
```

Edit 2:

If you only need all the integers, without name, without anything else, then you could either do this to get the `List<List<int>>`:

```
int userinput = 2015;
List<List<int>> intValuesOnly = harakatSininilMabsutoh
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.index == userinput)
    .DataValue
    .Select(y => y.IntegerValues)
    .ToList();
//Do whatever you want with intValuesOnly. This is everything that you have in a list of lists
```

or do this to get `List<int>` (flattened):

```
int userinput = 2015;
List<int> intValuesOnly = harakatSininilMabsutoh
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.index == userinput)
    .DataValue
    .SelectMany(y => y.IntegerValues)
    .ToList();
//Do whatever you want with intValuesOnly. This is everything that you have in single list
```

As `FirstOrDefault` may return `null` if the `userinput` is not found, note that, if you are not using C#6, you may want to consider two steps LINQ:

```
int userinput = 2015;
DataContainer requested = harakatSininilMabsutoh.FirstOrDefault(x => x.index == userinput);
if (requested == null) //FirstOrDefault of a class will return null if not found
    return;
List<List<int>> intValuesOnly = requested
    .Select(y => y.IntegerValues)
    .ToList();
//Do whatever you want with intValuesOnly. This is everything that you have in a list of lists
```

Comment: i don't wanna get the name , i just want to get the integervalues only
if you can i will make yours as accepting answer

Comment: "I want to get integer values only" You mean in the requested? or in the writing of the console? Or both?

Comment: yes both of them i just wanna show get integers value only , without string join

Comment: I see, and you don't want to print it out is it? Just the integer values of everything. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @ridwan I am not sure if the answer is what you really want, but you could see if it is. I edited it already.

Comment: Actually this question has relationship with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683461/make-a-better-approach-to-wrap-multiple-lists-dictionary-inside-class-and-loopi

I know how to loop the code but using Dictionary

Comment: Actually this question has relationship with this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683461/make-a-better-approach-to-wrap-multiple-lists-dictionary-inside-class-and-loopi
I know how to loop this using dictionary
but I confuse make loop wrapping class

Comment: @ridwan I think if you only want the `IntegerValues`, not the name or anything else, you could do the simple `LINQ` - you do not need `loop` at all. See my solution in the `Edit 2`

Comment: Using `FirstOrDefault` followed by `.DataValue` is going to throw an exception if the `userinput` isn't in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that in this line you have tried to use a type name as a property name:

```
public List<DataValue> DataValue { get; set; }
```

I've renamed this property to 'DataValues' as shown:

```
public List<DataValue> DataValues { get; set; }
```

You have a list ('harakatSininilMabsutoh'), each element of which is a DataContainer. Each DataContainer in the list has two properties: an index and a list of 'DataValues' (NB renamed from 'DataValue' in your post).

The looping logic you want will therefore be something like this:

```
var matchingYears = harakatSininilMabsutoh.Where(h => h.index == years);

foreach (var dataContainer in matchingYears)
{
    foreach (var item in dataContainer.DataValues)
    {
        // Action required on each DataValue:
        Debug.Print(item.name + " " + string.Join(",", item.IntegerValues));
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the following 'using' statement to your class, since 'Where' is a LINQ extension method:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If you know that there will be exactly one matching year, you could add `First()` and remove the outer `foreach` loop. If you know there will be at most one matching year (but there could be zero), you can still remove the outer `foreach` loop but you should use `FirstOrDefault()` instead and test for null.

Comment: i don't wanna get the name , i just want to get the integer values only
if you can i will make yours as accepting answer

Comment: As @Ian says, it sounds like you don't need a loop at all... his edited answer pretty much covers it.